# Atom Editor turn off same term highlighting for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

Is there a way to turn off *just* the same term highlighting for TypeScript? See attached image.

I have `atom-typescript` (12.7.3) installed as well as `core/language-typescript` (0.4.11). I don't see any options in the Settings for either to turn this feature off.

—

**I would like to turn this off**:

[image: Screenshot of example code with same term highlighting.]

Comment: FWIW, in VS Code it's called "Occurrences Highlight" in the text editor settings. So if Atom uses similar terminology...

Comment: Why the downvote? Is it **really** easy to find or something?

Comment: Not for me! (Unless I'm an idiot… which is probable) Perhaps I should remove the commentary about being unpleasant with CSS-in-JS. Also I don't see anything about occurrence highlights — thanks though